# 'PCDATA invalid Char value' on RSS Script

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, blogs

I'm using the following script to read an external RSS feed and output news on a website I'm working on:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.somewebsite.com/news/rss.xml');
    $feed = array();

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array (
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
            array_push($feed, $item);
        }

    $limit = 8;
    $count = 1;
?>

<?php for ($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) : ?>

    <?php

        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    ?>

    <section class="grid_3">
        <div class="content">

            <span class="date"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $date; ?></a></span>
            <h6><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h6>

        </div>
    </section>

    <?php $count ++; ?>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

It worked fine the other day, but now I've had another look it's bringing up a load of errors along the lines of:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: PCDATA invalid Char value 31

As well as this, the dates of the posts are showing up as

> Thursday January 01, 1970

Does anyone know what might be wrong? Could this be something to do with the external RSS feed? That still looks fine when viewed in my browser though

Comment: do you have that live sample feed?

Comment: @Ghost yup here you go http://bit.ly/1te3QoD

Comment: @pealo86 Are you still having this issue? I couldn't replicate it--sound like it was a temporary problem with the RSS feed.

Comment: @ialarmedalien sorry for the late response, yes I think it must have just been that... as it started working again without me changing anything!